# Can't install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient in Nuget Package Manager

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

Can't install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient in Nuget Package Manager.This error was faced "An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config' in project '##' No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.serviceModel". How to solve this?

[Can't install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLj1i.png)

## Update

I tried to install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient on another layer of project and problem solved.

Comment: I didn't encounter any problems while I am installing the package. I have Visual Studio Professional 2017 and my nuget version is 4.5.0.4685. What is your system?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 Enterprise and my Nuget Package Manager version is 3.4.4. It's fine on new project but the old existing one. In my new project when I install these packages web.config was change by adding  <extensions> tab in <system.serviceModel>. In my old project these changes not perform and the error occurred. I think this is the source of my error and I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the missing <extensions><system.serviceModel> tag to the config?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not worked. VS keeping force close when I collapse and expand <extensions> tag.

Comment: Hey Burak, I tried to install it on another layer and it's succeeded. Problem solved xD

Comment: Glad you did, mate. :)